# How can I start the Windows Terminal maximized by default?

Tags: windows-terminal

Is there a way to force the Windows Terminal to start maximized (not full-screen - I still want my taskbar to be there) by default?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/288) by default is not possible. The easiest way is ALT + ENTER once it opens, but that's fullscreen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you mean the new Windows terminal (preview), that is possible with adding:

"launchMode": "maximized"

to the "globals" section

Source: *[Windows Terminal Preview 1910 Release](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1910-release/)*

Comment: As of 2021 (Windows Terminal version 1.5.10411.0) `"launchMode": "fullscreen"` works for me instead of `maximized`. Other than that you can always press F11 to toggle fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what @Petar said, [since preview v.1.1.1671.0](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.1.1671.0), `--fullscreen` and `--maximized` are two optional switches for the `wt` execution alias if you're automating something and trying to run the terminal maximized only sometimes.

So, these two ways of launching the terminal from the command line are now an option:

```sh
wt --maximized

wt --fullscreen
```